# Introduction to theoretical computer science for research mathematicians

Tags: reference-request

> Are there any references on theoretical computer science aimed at people with a background in research mathematics?

For reference, I spend my time thinking about category theory and set theory most days. I've begun programming in haskell and it feels very intuitive now that I'm starting to get the whole 'type' syntax down, but reading through some [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-with-project-euler-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell/6964760#6964760) comparing haskell to other languages got me thinking about the foundations of programming, and now here I am.

Some light searching revealed that Knuth has a [series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321751043) considered a standard reference by many; I'm familiar with Knuth as a mathematician and fond of his work, so this seems promising. I've also heard that the [computing handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439898448) is widely considered a standard reference.

Are there any standard references I'm missing, or narrower ones geared towards set/category theorists? Research papers are certainly welcome, and any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at semantics of programming languages textbooks that rely on category theory.

For instance:
Check out the books advised [here][1].

This is part of theoretical computer science. Dana Scott's work is particularly relevant. As is Lawvvere's later work, topos theoretic applications etc.
[1]: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/books-on-programming-language-semantics